# How to mathematically derive Height & number of Leafs of this Recursion Tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, logarithm, recurrence

I was studying following tree and get stuck on deriving it's Height & number of Leafs:
[image: image from clrs book]

**It says the height is [log<sub>b</sub>n ]: How to derive it?**
(also i think height = [log<sub>b</sub>n] + 1)

**How They derive number of Leafs:**
**a<sup>log<sub>b</sub>n</sup> = n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>**

Please help me to  mathematically derive Height & number of Leafs of this Recursion Tree in a very simple way.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Height** 
The top of the tree begins with **n** and for every step down it is divided by **b**. So it goes n, n/b, n/b<sup>2</sup>,...,1. To find the height we need to find a **k** such that n / b<sup>k</sup> = 1 or **b<sup>k</sup> = n**, which gives **k = log<sub>b</sub>n**.

**Number of leaves** 
For every step down the tree, the leaves are multiplied by **a** times. The number of leaves is **a<sup>k</sup>**, where k is the number of steps or height of the tree.
**The number of leaves = a<sup>log<sub>b</sub>n</sup>.**

Comment: Thanks @Sneha.Very Nice & Simple explanation.However,I used an example to test the tree height. e.g: if b=2 and n = 8  then the tree expands from 8,4,2,1 up to 4 levels, but log b^n = log2^8 = 3 Not 4 ?  can you please explain more.thanks

Comment: Height of the tree is usually measured as the number of steps from the root of the tree. So in this case, 8 being the root - 4,2,1 are the levels. But if you want to add the root also as a level, then the answer is logb^n + 1.

Comment: Thanks @Sneha.Also I did undarstand a ^ (log b n). But how **a ^ (log b n)** becomes **n^log(b a)** please help.thanks

Comment: Assume a^(log b n) = p. This implies (log b n) = (log a p).
(log b n) = log n/ log b and log a p = log p/ log a.
**log p = (log n* log a)/ log b**
Assume n^ (log b a) = q. Similarly by above logic, we can derive that
**log q = (log n* log a)/ log b.**
Therefore p = q.